# How do I click on specific part of the image on webdriver? (python)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to click on particular image in the below. Is it possible to achieve this in selenium?

```
   <div class="gc__1YQFv">
    <div class="gc__2Qtwp">
        <span class="gc__2T7lQ">
                Please confirm yourself
        </span>
        <span class="gc__2e8f-">
            tip for users click
        </span>
    </div>
<div>
<img class="gc__3_EfD" src="image Source">
```

Comment: please add the html of the element that holds all these images. Make sure you add the html between  `\`\`\`` rather as an image.

Comment: I guess doesnt need html because I need an way o click inside this image and not the whole image

Comment: example I need to click on the clock inside the image how do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, without html code it's hard to provide the solution.

Comment: i just need to know how do i click on specific width and height from the image

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, but check if [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset) helps. You can use `move_to_element_with_offset()` to move your cursor to given offset from top left corner of an element(Image in your case). Then you just need to perform `click()` at that position. If you need more help, please share your issue more clearly.

Comment: how big is the image and where exactly do you want to click it? Can you highlight on paint and upload how it looks in the site?